# Match specific length x or y

Tags: regex

*I'd like a regex that is either X or Y characters long*. For example, match a string that is either 8 or 11 characters long. I have currently implemented this like so: `^([0-9]{8}|[0-9]{11})$`.

I could also implement it as: `^[0-9]{8}([0-9]{3})?$`

My question is: **Can I have this regex without duplicating the `[0-9]` part** (which is more complex than this simple `\d` example)?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is one way:

```
^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{8}|.{11})$
```

or alternatively, if you want to do the length check first,

```
^(?=(?:.{8}|.{11})$)[0-9]*$
```

That way, you have the complicated part only once and a generic `.` for the length check.

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
(?=     # Assert that the following regex can be matched here:
 [0-9]* # any number of digits (and nothing but digits)
 $      # until end of string
)       # (End of lookahead)
(?:     # Match either
 .{8}   # 8 characters
|       # or
 .{11}  # 11 characters
)       # (End of alternation)
$       # End of string
```

Comment: Very nice... I'll have to learn more about these lookaheads :)

Comment: Beware: If you take the `^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{8}|.{11})$` version, it might be buggy for IE5-8 as explained [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug). Switch to Tim's alternate version and it does work for all browsers.

Comment: Note both versions are not supported by XML schema due to the non-capturing group (?:).

Comment: (?=^(.{8}|.{11})$)^[0-9]*$ since ?= does not capture the pattern so we can omit '?:'

Comment: @user1438644: A lookahead does not participate in the match, but if there are capturing groups within, they *will*  capture their contents. Since capturing and storing slows a regex down, I only use capturing groups when I need them. That's why I wouldn't omit the `?:` part.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl, you could do:

```perl
my $re = qr/here_is_your_regex_part/;
my $full_regex = qr/$re{8}(?:$re{3})?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of us looking to capture different lengths of the same multiple try this.

`^(?:[0-9]{32})+$`

Where `32` is the multiple you want to capture all lengths for (32, 64, 96, ...).