# Is it possible to match different specific length using RegExp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that with JS RegExp I can match:

- Exact length; `/^[a-zA-Z]{7}$/`
- A length range; `/^[a-zA-Z]{3,7}$/`
- A minimum length; `/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/`

What if I wanna match varying specific lengths? Something like: `/^[a-zA-Z]{2|4|6}$/` meaning that the string must have either length of 2, 4 or 6 characters. Can I do it using JavaScript's RegExp?

I tried googling but couldn't find a way to search for this specific case, I always end up finding how to match length ranges.

**Scenario**: I currently have this `if` statement that I would like to make shorter:

```
if(typeof ean !== 'string' || !/^\d+$/.test(ean) || [8, 12, 13, 14].indexOf(ean.length) === -1) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784338/match-specific-length-x-or-y

Comment: No, regex won't let you match using a list like that. You could use `^[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:[a-zA-Z]{2})?)?$` instead of an alternation.

Comment: If you're really trying to match lengths 2, 4, and 6, you could get clever and do `/^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}){1,3}$/`. But this isn't a good, clean solution; it's a clever one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the Regex OR `|` pattern, but it will require some repetition:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{6})$/
```

Note that the `(?:...)` part is just a non-capturing group, which is used to make all of the alternatives "act as one." Without it, the `^` and `$` would have to be included in each alternative.

In your specific case, perhaps try:

```
/^(?:\d{8}|\d{12,14})$/
```