# Rule validation for string length in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to validate a string whose length is exactly 6 OR 8. How could I make the rule for this validation?

The number must be 6 OR 8, it cannot be between 6 and 8.

Comment: What have you tried? Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php twice? Use regex?

Comment: yes, but if(strlen($abc) != 6 || strlen($abc) != 8), it doesn't work

Comment: For negatives, you need `&&`. Otherwise, it would be `if(strlen($abc) == 6 || strlen($abc) == 8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to make your own validator, since Laravel's validation comes with a [regex validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-regex), so you could just do:

```
[
    ...
    'parameter' => 'regex:/^(.{6}|.{8})$/g',
    ...
]
```

Regex stolen and adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784338/match-specific-length-x-or-y) but you can test it [here](https://regexr.com/7140b)

**Regex Explanation:**

```
^    # Start of string
(    # Start capture group
.    # Matches any character except line breaks
{6}  # Quantifier that only matches 6 preceding tokens (.)
|    # OR operator
.    # Matches any character except line breaks
{8}  # Quantifier that only matches 8 preceding tokens (.)
)    # End capture group
$    # End of string
```

---

**OLD ANSWER (unnecessarily complicated)**

```
[
    ...
    'parameter' => 'regex:/^(?=.*$)(?:.{6}|.{8})$/g',
    ...
]
```

**Regex Explanation:**

```
^    # Start of string
(?=  # Start of positive lookahead
.*   # Matches any character except line breaks 0 or more times
$    # End of string
)    # End of positive lookahead
(?:  # Start of non-capturing group
.{6} # Matches any character except line breaks exactly 6 times
|    # OR operator
.{8} # Matches any character except line breaks exactly 8 times
)    # End non-capturing group
$    # End of string
```

Comment: could you explain to me how the symbols in this regex you improvised work?

Comment: @flashstar while writing regex explanation I realized that the original regex is way more complicated than it has to be so I changed the answer. I included explanations for both the original and the new, simpler regex. But please note that I'm really not an expert for writing regular expressions, so there may be an even simpler way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom rule.

In the sample below, I used the Closure to create a custom rule, but you can create a rule object to reuse it.

I used the `mb_strlen` instead of `strlen` to cover multibyte. (UTF8 chars)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => [
            'required',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (!(mb_strlen($value) == 8 || mb_strlen($value) == 6))
                {
                    $fail('The ' . $attribute . ' is invalid.');
                }
            },
        ],
    ]);

    dd($validator->errors());
});
```

Comment: Use || instead of nested if (OR operator)

Answer (score 0):

Try saving string length first and then check with if conditions.

```
$str = “hellowld”;
$len = strlen($str);
If($len == 6 || $len == 8)
    //do something 
Else
    //throw error
```

or use regex validation rule for length as:

```
 /^[68]+$/
```

For string length.